# How to generate a vector of pseudo random numbers from another vector (as seeds)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, vector, random-seed

I want to generate a vector pseudo-random numbers (between 0 and 1) from another vector of float point number (between 0 and 1) in Python, so that the same float point number will give rise to the same pseudo-random number.

For example, given the vector `[0.124, 0.258, 0.697, 0.124]`, then I would like receive a vector like `[0.358, 0.695, 0.976 ,0.358]`.

Is there any easy way to implement this? Is it possible to use the `numpy.random` package to implement this?

Comment: What python version do you use?

Comment: Python 3. Does the version matter?

Comment: user3821012: No, the Python version doesn't matter much wrt this question.

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following:

```
inputvector  = [0.124, 0.258, 0.697, 0.124]
endvector = []
for numb in inputvector:
    seed = int(str(numb)[2:])
    random.seed(seed)
    endvector.append(random.random())
```

This outputs:

```
endvector
[0.9607807567552326, 0.6536579270711469, 0.1367864649789986, 0.9607807567552326]
```

By using the decimal part of your number as an integer seed, you can generate pseudo-random numbers that repeat themselves when using the same initial float.

Answer (score 0):

Another similar way using numpy:

```
import numpy as np
seeds = [0.124, 0.258, 0.697, 0.124]
_, seeds = np.unique(seeds, return_inverse=True)
a = []
for seed in seeds:
  np.random.seed(seed)
  a.append(np.random.rand())
#output    
#[0.5488135 0.417022  0.4359949 0.5488135]
```